# Почему блоки не плавающие и не принимают ширину указанную для класса grid4

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-grid, grid

Использую `CSS фреймворк` ***`960gs`***.  В этой системе сеток все классы `grid_...` начиная от `grid_1 до grid_12` имеют свойство `float: left`.

Для `grid_1` установлена ширина в ***60px*** и внешние отступы с обоих сторон по ***10px***, того блок с классом `grid_1` будет занимать пространство ***80px***, `grid_2 - 160px`, `grid_3 - 240px`, `grid4 - 320px` соответственно и т.д. `grid_12 и container_12` занимают пространство в ***960px***.

Вопрос: почему блоки `#column1, #column2, #column3` не плавают влево и не занимают ***320px*** каждый?

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

#nav,
#characteristic,
#footer {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#characteristic {
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#column1,
#column2,
#column3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_12 clearfix">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Логотип</h1>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Домой</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Товары</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="characteristic" class="grid_12">
    Характеристики
  </div>
  <div id="column1" class="grid_4">
    Колонка1
  </div>
  <div id="column2" class="grid_4">
    Колонка2
  </div>
  <div id="column3" class="grid_4">
    Колонка3
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="footer" class="grid_12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Напишите стили для grid_12 и grid_4, тогда можна будет что-то отписать, или вы используете библиотеки. Опишите более детально. А то на ваш воспрос - простойт ответ - что-то не так с кодов, где-то у вас.

Comment: @klifort я использую фреймворк 960gs

Comment: `grid`, `flex` - создан для того что бы упростить нам жизнь...  Зачем тут использовать `float` и зачем элементам дочерним задавать `display: inline;`? Ты не совсем понимаешь, что такое `grid` и с чем его едят... И прежде чем использовать чужие наработки в виде  библиотек  и фрейворков напиши сам... Вручную...   Чтобы понимать что творится внутри верстки и в стилях...

Answer (score 1):

Импортировал файл css c главной страницы `https://960.gs/css/master.min.css` и (если посмотреть в код) видно что `width` приписал фиксированый для `grid_4` `300px` + у вас есть приписаны `padding :20px;` что уже больше 1200px как указано для `container_12`

```css
@import url("https://960.gs/css/master.min.css");
ul {
    text-align: center;
   }
   li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;
   }
   a {
    color: #000;
   }
   #nav, #characteristic, #footer {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   #characteristic {
    height: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
   #column1, #column2, #column3 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
   }
   .clear {
    clear: both;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container_12 clearfix">
   <div id="header">
    <h1>Логотип</h1>
    <div id="nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Домой</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Товары</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="characteristic" class="grid_12">
    Характеристики
   </div>
   <div id="column1" class="grid_4">
    Колонка1
   </div>
   <div id="column2" class="grid_4">
    Колонка2
   </div>
   <div id="column3" class="grid_4">
    Колонка3
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div id="footer" class="grid_12"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Ну если убрать padding (ну или применить свойство border-sizing: border-box), то всё равно работать не будет.

Comment: Хотя у Вас всё работает... хммм....

Comment: Не поверите....

Comment: Вся проблема была в том, что в <link> я забыл написать rel="stylesheet". Дописал, внёс пару правок и... Всё работает :D

Comment: Да, бывает, мелочь а весь проект не работает )))